# Batch file just echos out the script and doesn't run

Tags: batch-file

I've got the following script but it just seems to echo out the entire script and not actually run

```
set myRoot = %systemroot%
set myFont = "\fonts\myfontname-Light.ttf"
set myFull = %myRoot% %myFont%
IF EXIST {%myFull%} (
echo "hi"
) ELSE (
cscript //NoLogo //B font.vbs
)
```

Any hints would be greatly appreciated

Tom

Comment: Why are you doubling the slashes on the `cscript` command?

Comment: `set myFull = %myRoot%` <--- the spaces in these set statements are being put in the variable name and the variable.  Remove them.

Comment: @MarkReed try `cscript /?`.Despite it works with sinlge slashes too

Comment: @npocmaka the `//nologo` in the help is a typo.  Two work but aren't needed.

Comment: @foxidrive I know, but often the help misleads the cscript users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "myRoot=%systemroot%"
set "myFont=\fonts\myfontname-Light.ttf"
set "myFull=%myRoot%%myFont%"
IF EXIST "%myFull%" (
  echo "hi"
) ELSE (
  cscript /NoLogo /B font.vbs
)
```

Comment: Hey - Thanks for that. It still doesn't seem to launch the vbs script though

Comment: is it in the same directory?

Comment: My mistake, i missed a "! - Thanks a lot mate